# @RepositoryEventHandler methods not called for @Modifying methods

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-data-rest

I have an event handler class as follows:

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(DonationOffer.class)
public class DonationOfferEventHandler {

    @Autowired
    DonationOfferNotificationService notificationService;

    @HandleAfterSave
    public void handleAfterSave(DonationOffer donationOffer){

        Integer donationOfferId = donationOffer.getDonationOfferId();
        System.out.println("updating donation offer");

        switch (donationOffer.getOfferStatus()){
            case Accepted:
                notificationService.generateAcceptedNotification(donationOfferId);
                break;
            case Rejected:
                notificationService.generateRejectedNotification(donationOfferId);
                break;
            case Cancelled:
                notificationService.generateCancelledNotification(donationOfferId);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And spring repo as follows:

```
@Transactional
public interface DonationOfferRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DonationOffer,Integer>{

    @Modifying
    @Query(
            "update DonationOffer d " +
                    "set offerStatus = :offerStatus " +
                    "where d.donationOfferId = :donationOfferId"
    )
    @RestResource(path="updateStatus")
    int updateStatus(
            @Param("donationOfferId") Integer donationOfferId,
            @Param("offerStatus") OfferStatus offerStatus
    );
}
```

Event handler is called in case of PUT request by the problem is that @HandleAfterSave method is not being called when I call updateStatus() i.e.,

```
a get request to /api/donationOffers/search/updateStatus?donationOfferId=45&offerStatus=Cancelled
```

Can any one help if I am missing something or is it the default behavior that @HandleAfterSave would be called only with PUT request ?

UPDATE:
I have created a method to test event handler with repo save method as follows. Event handler is not called in this case also.

```
@GetMapping(value="/savetest")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity saveTesT(){
        DonationOffer donationOffer = donationOfferRepo.findOne(1);

        donationOffer.setOfferedBottles(donationOffer.getOfferedBottles()+1);

        donationOfferRepo.save(donationOffer);

        return new ResponseEntity(new StringWrapper("OK"), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to trigger event from HandleBeforeSave you need to execute PUT request. If you are doing POST request than the correct event handler would be HandleBeforeCreate.

UPDATE:i would guess that the listener method does not get invoked for the same reason as to why Queries do not invoke JPA prePersist, postPersist, preUpdate ... and so on events. Queries have different execution route as to EntityManager.persis , update.   Entity manager works on the foundation of identity , therefore it can guarantee that an entity has actually been updates. Same can not be told when you use a Query. Normally entity manager would execute one query to fetch the entity than it will be analysed for changes and then UPDATE will happen, or will not happen in case of no changes. There is no mechanism to tell if update has really happened when query is executed.

According to the documentation @Modifying annotation is not guaranteeing that modification will actually happen. What it is guaranteeing is that the session will be cleared after method invokation. The reasoning behind this is again that the queries have different execution route than the normal persist, merge methods and you can not guarantee that the session will keep integrity. Therefore @Modifying will guarantee it has been cleared.

Comment: I know that PUT would trigger it but thats exactly my question. Why \@HandleAfterSave is not called with \@Modifying query method.

Comment: @ArslanAnjum Is the method invoked if you update through the repository save method?

Comment: No it doesn't come in event handler method with repo.save(object) method.

Comment: So can we achieve such functionality with @Modifying queries by some other way?

Comment: Invoking the save method should have invoked the listener if there has been change in the state of the DonationOffer. If the listener has not been executed when save was invoked, then this mean yu have misconfiguration. Is it possible that your @Component DonationOfferEventHandler falls outside of the component scanning ?

Comment: event handler is invoked with PUT method so I think @ComponentScan is working. I am incrementing a field to make sure that entity changes each time.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the code in which I am testing repo save method. See the updated question

Comment: @ArslanAnjum in my opinion you should not use updating query for this type of functionality. There is no guarantee , the update has actually happened, no matter if your logic implicitly has done the modification.

If I was you I would have used HandlerInterceptor for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Check also TransactionalEventListener you can bind it to the transaction completion / the sending of the notification.